# Attribute error: 'app' object has no attribute 'calc'

Tags: python, calculator

I've been making a calculator in python for a bit, and just as I thought I finished it, it gave me an error which said "Attribute error: 'app' object has no attribute 'calc'. Can someone help me? Here is the code. (btw if you're having a bad day, keep scrolling I don't want anyone telling me that I'm a mindless skid who doesn't know how to program a simple calculator)

```
from tkinter import*

def iCalc(source, side):
storeObj = Frame (source, borderwidth=4, bd=4, bg="orange")
storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
return storeObj

def button (source, side, text, command = None) :
storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
return storeObj

class app(Frame):
def __init__(self) :
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.option_add('*Font', 'arial 20 bold')
    self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    self.master.title('Calculator')


        
    display = StringVar()
    Entry(self, relief= None, 
    textvariable=display, justify='right', bd=30, bg="orange").pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)


    for clearBut in (["CE"], ["C"]):
        erase = iCalc(self, TOP)
        for ichar in clearBut:
            button(erase, LEFT, ichar,
            lambda storeObj=display, q=ichar: storeObj.set(''))


    for NumBut in ("789/", "456*", "321-", "0.+") :
        FunctionNum = iCalc(self, TOP)
        for char in NumBut:
            button(FunctionNum, LEFT, char,
            lambda storeObj=display, q=char: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + q))


    EqualsButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
    for iEquals in "=":
        if iEquals == "=":
            btniEquals = button(EqualsButton,LEFT, iEquals)
            btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
            lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
    
        else:
            btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals,
            lambda storeObj=display, s=' %s '%iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))



if __name__ == '__main__':
app () .mainloop()
```

Comment: `s.calc(storeObj)`: what is `calc`? It isn't defined anywhere here.

Comment: Not really sure, I've been following a tutorial from youtube. I can give you the link if you want.

Comment: And as a side note: `for iEquals in "=": if iEquals == "=":` is a bit odd. That loop will only iterate once, and `iEquals == "="` will *always* be true.

Comment: You seem to have missed some code that they wrote. Your code is expecting the `app` class to have a `calc` method (`def calc(self, ...)`), but your code is missing that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry if someone has been rude to you on this platform. We are all learning here and nobody should call each other a mindless skid.

In any case, I can see that in line `lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')`. You have used `s.calc` but you haven't defined the it anywhere. You need to define a new `calc()` function.

Comment: `iCalc` isn't a method, so that will give a different error.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough it's defined outside the class. They will have to make a new function calc which they probably missed in the tutorial.

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for your answer. I've tried changing it to iCalc, but when I do that,it says that iCalc is not defined in the object 'app'. I tried defining iCalc inside the app class,but it just gives me a lot of errors.

Comment: Yeah, just make a new calc function which you might have missed in the video. You can share the link to the video and we can help out.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me. I've found that the person who made the tutorial had written some code off camera and didn't show it before running his script. Although,he has shown it after running it. Really helped me out guys,and sorry if I wasted your time being careless.

Comment: @itzjustaki Out of curiosity, what's the link?

Comment: Here it is. Very helpful video. https://youtu.be/J-mvqlkHOHY

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was gonna ask the same thing lol and itzustaki you didn't waste our time. Chill out, man!

Comment: Haha, I just feel a bit bad that i didn't have patience to watch the whole video before turning to stackoverflow. Thanks again guys!

Comment: @itzjustaki It should be said, that code actually has a lot of problems. His naming is quite poor, and as I mentioned in a comment on your question, some of his code doesn't even make sense. I'd be cautious learning from them. You don't want to learn bad habits in the beginning.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the heads up. I'll definitely try to find a more reliable source for learning python.